# Is jfxrt.jar included in Java 8?

Tags: java, maven, javafx, maven-compiler-plugin

I used to include the jfxrt.jar when compiling my JavaFX project with Maven like that :

```
 <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${maven.compiler.plugin}</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>${maven.compile.source}</source>
                <target>${maven.compile.target}</target>
                <compilerArguments>
                    <bootclasspath>${sun.boot.class.path}${path.separator}${shuttlefx.jre}/lib/jfxrt.jar</bootclasspath>
                </compilerArguments>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

But do I still need to add the bootclasspath argument with the latest Oracle JDK 8 version ?

Comment: In Oracle JDK8 it is no longer in `lib`, but in `lib/ext`, which is part of the default boot class path. I don't use Maven for project builds, but as I understand it you should no longer need the `bootclasspath` element.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes it is provided with the from JDK 8.

You can have a look at the **[original site](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/overview/javafx-overview-2158620.html)**

you can also check it at ..\Java\jdkversion\lib\ext\jfxrt.jar